# Get property value using System.getProperty("Some_key") as key

Tags: java, spring

Here is my class with spring annotations

```
@Component
Class XyzPropeties {
    @Value("${#{systemProperties['xyz']}}"); //Tried but it doesn't work
    private xyzValue;
}
```

xyz.properties

```
abc=abcValue
```

So I'm setting `System.setProperty("xyz", "abc");` and expecting the 'abcValue' of XyzProperties should yeild abcValue.

Thanks.

***Answer to own question***

This is the answer ->***`@Value("${${xyz}}")`*** //Did a reverse engineering, Spring recursively evaluates the expression, it first evaluates `${xyz}` which evaluates to `abc` then evaluates `${abc}` which evaluates `abcValue` and then there is no further evaluation so it returns the value `abcValue`

Comment: A bit more context might be useful … from where comes `@Component` and `@value`, to start with?

Comment: Spring annotations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to access the value of attribute xyzValue of XyzProperties class anywhere of your code. And this value is stored in xyz.properties file.

A simpler way to to this is to store the properties in the application.properties file, stored in "resources" folder in your spring application. And to use the properties, you may use a singleton class:

```
class Example {

    private static Example instance = null;

    @Value(${your.property.key.on.application.properties})
    private String value;

    private Example(){}

    public static Example getInstance(){
         if(instance == null){
               instance = new Example();
         }
         return instance;
    }

    public String getValue(){
       return value;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It did not. Isn't it too obvious, Wouldn't have asked the question in that way if it is the case.